# python cursor return only those rows which first column is not empty

Tags: python

In Python 3.8, I have a select query.

```
dbconn.execute("select name, id, date from test_table")
```

That query returned always wrong number of rows. After too much debugging, I was able to fix it by only replacing id column place with name column and it started working normally.

The issue was with empty value for name column for some rows.

It means, python cursor returns only those rows which first column is not empty. Do I miss anything in my conclusion?

Comment: Can you share with us an image or txt include your table structure and values?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database integrity, it might be that some of the entries are corrupted thus failing. Cuz I had issue before that the query is failing (wrong number of output) at some point due to integrity issue.

1 thing also is instead of returning the row as list/tuple, try it with dictionary-like with key-value pair.

`dbconn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`